# Delegate and Event : C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c#-4.0

I've got a question on events and delegates in C#. I saw in many codes that they've used the `event` and `delegate` keyword to create an event trigger. Let's skip that for now, what concerned me a lot was the functions that the event triggered or rather the functions that were invoked here is the scope snippet.

```
public delegate void EventHandler();
class Program
{
    //Note : Assigning the evet to the delegate
    public static event EventHandler _show;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _show += new EventHandler(Dog);
        _show += new EventHandler(Cat);
        _show.Invoke();                   
    }

    static void Dog() {
        Console.WriteLine("Doggie");
    }

    static void Cat(){
        Console.WriteLine("Pussy");
    }

}
```

`

As you can see there are several functions called Dog / Cat. There return types are `void` but when you execute it looks like a `string` value is returned to the event `_show`. Can someone explain whats going on here?

Comment: `There return types are void but when you execute it looks like a string value is returned to the event _show` Can you explain what you mean there? The `_show.Invoke()` method returns nothing and nor does `_show()`. It's simply void.

Comment: Are you saying that the `+=` makes you think it's a string?

Comment: Forget what I said, can you please explain what goes on here?

Comment: OT: public members should not start with an `_`. Name it `event Show`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are interpreting the syntax wrongly.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _show += new EventHandler(Dog);
        _show += new EventHandler(Cat);
        _show.Invoke();                   
    }
```

The `_show += new EventHandler(Dog)` will just queue the function call of `Dog()` . So its like holding all the function calls in a queue and then executing them in FIFO order.

You are not returning anything here. Only all of your functions are getting called sequentially and then values are getting printed.

Comment: No, the `+=` does not queue any function calls. It subscribes a method to an event but this could be used in 0 or in 1000 function calls.

Answer (score 0):

The `show` Event just run the `Dog` and then run `Cat` Methods. Obviously, it will print "Doggie" and "Pussy".

If you want to return a string:

```
static string Dog() {
       // Console.WriteLine("Doggie");
       return "Doggie";
}
```

and change the `delegate` decalre:

```
public delegate string EventHandler();
```